# splash screen : showing weird image at the top left

Tags: java, android, xml, splash-screen

[image]

// SplashActivity

```
onCreate
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
```

// activity_splash.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
```

// Android Manifest . xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".common.activity.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

// SplashTheme

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="TransparentStatusbar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_drawable</item>
</style>
```

// splash_drawable.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:opacity="opaque">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/edit_text_background"/> //color code : #20FFFFFF

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

- Why am i getting weird image at top left. ?
- Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, this is problem of your device's hardware. Have you tried deploying it on any other machine?

Comment: does "yup" mean that you have tried another machine and the problem is there as well or otherwise (the problem doesn't appear there)?

Comment: yes i have tried in other devices. but this issue comes in samsung S4 device not is other devices. .